# Laravel 5.4, Always logging "Unauthenticated." to log file and some unknown errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm building a Laravel 5.4 application and have setup my **routes\web.php** as below:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'PublicController@home')->name('home');

Route::get('/about', 'PublicController@about')->name('about');
Route::get('/contact', 'PublicController@contact')->name('contact');
Route::post('/contact', 'PublicController@sendMessage')->name('contact.send');

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Auth::routes();
    Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {

        Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');

        Route::get('user', 'UserController@index')->name('user.profile');
        Route::post('user/update', 'UserController@update')->name('user.update');
    });
});
```

To remove additional track & trace my modified **App\Exceptions\Handler;** class is as below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{

    protected $dontReport = [
        \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
        \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
        \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
    ];

    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        if (!config('app.debug')) {
            \Log::error('['.$e->getCode().'] "'.$e->getMessage().'" on line '.$e->getTrace()[0]['line'].' of file '.$e->getTrace()[0]['file']);
        } else {
            parent::report($e);
        }
    }

    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

        return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
    }
}
```

In my **config\app.php** file I have changed the log level as below:

```
'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'error'),
```

Now whenever, I access any public route e.g. mydomain.com/ or mydomain.com/about, the redirects works fine without any front end error, but Laravel is logging below error into the log file:

```
[2019-05-21 05:12:32] production.ERROR: [0] "" on line 546 of file
D:\laragon\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php
```

And if I access any admin (protected) routes e.g. mydomain.com/admin or mydomain.com/admin/user, again there are no errors at the front end but getting log entries as below:

```
[2019-05-21 05:12:47] production.ERROR: [0] "Unauthenticated." on line 294 of file
 D:\laragon\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php  
[2019-05-21 05:12:47] production.ERROR: [0] "" on line 546 of file
 D:\laragon\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php
```

**Now my questions are:**

1. Why am I getting "Unauthenticated." log entry in production environment?
2. Why laravel is logging an empty routing error *(production.ERROR: [0] "" on line 546)*, while accessing any public or protected routes?

**P.S.** I'm using PHP version  7.2.11

Comment: try putting the `Auth::routes();` out of the `Route::prefix('admin')->group(function ()`

Comment: Already did that, and still getting the same error log entries. Further putting ```Auth::routes();``` outside the prefix group will also remove prefix admin/login or admin/dashboard from the back end Urls.

Comment: if you run `php artisan route:list` it show any error?

Comment: No errors at all, I even tried running all possible artisan commands like ```route:clear```, ```route:cache```, ```config:clear```, ```config:cache```, ```clear-compile``` etc. and every command ran successfully